# GoogleMap is not refreshed when behind a transparent activity

Tags: android, android-activity, google-maps-android-api-2

In my application I have a main activity with a GoogleMap fragment inside it. The map often moves its camera and draws markers and polylines without a direct user interaction (i.e to follow a target).

The problem occurs when I start other translucent/transparent activities on top of that main one. I cannot use dialogs, views of fragments, unfortunately I have to use only activities. So I declared their style as:

```
<style name="AppTheme.Transparent" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackgroundCacheHint">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
</style>
```

These activities have some views placed on top of a semi-transparent black background, so one can see the map behind them. The problem is that the **map drawing is not updated at all while behind these activities**, despite the fact that the code that, for example, move the camera actually runs (I can see it from logs or debugging). The map drawing is updated correctly only after (and immediately) the overlay translucent activity is closed. The strange fact is that other views placed on the main activity (for example, text views showing target coordinates) are correctly updated while behind the translucent activity, also if they are placed on top of the maps.

Is there someone who knows why is this happening, and if there is a way to force map redrawing while host activity is not in the foreground?

Comment: I think it goes to background, calling onPause(). This will stop most of the process on the map (work as intended). I don't know how you can stop this from happening.

Comment: @DavidCorsalini If so, I will try to use a MapView instead of SupportMapFragment, avoid *routing* onPause/onResume activity lifecycle events as the official guide suggests...

Comment: I did something like that but it was kind of a hack. I had a very small view 1dp by 1dp in xml. Made it public static view in java.I assigned the view to redraw map in onclick listener. then from another activity or thread you can use MapActivityTest.mySmallView.performClick();

Comment: @DavidCorsalini onPause() was the problem. I solved as I said yesterday, using a MapView instead of a SupportMapFragment, and forwarding map onPause/onResume in activity's onStop/onStart instead. This way map's onPause is called only when activity is completely invisible to user, and not when it's under a dimmed background of a transparent activity. Map loading and movements are very slow when in background (I can't get why), but at least now it works, it's an acceptable compromise. If you want to write your catch as an answer, I will be happy to accept it.